# How come my navigation bar disappears if I launch my app from a push notification?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, navigation, push-notification

I have an app where there is a child view controller containing a list of all the push notifications. As a result, I want to load this view controller when the user launches the app from the push notification. I am launching the right view controller (NotifcationsViewController) but it does not include the navigation bar it is suppose to have. It only has the navigation bar if I initiate the controller from a parent. The following code is in my appDelegate.m file.

```
- (void) application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
```

{

```
if ( application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateInactive || application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateBackground  )
{
    UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard"
                                                             bundle: nil];
    UINavigationController *nav = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NotificationsViewController"];
    [_window setRootViewController:nav];

     }
}
```

NotificationsViewController has/should have a left nav bar item that pops back to its parentViewController.

Comment: Is NotificationsViewController a UINavigationController? Your naming scheme suggests otherwise.

Comment: NotifciationsViewController is a view controller, with an navigation bar inferred

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
if ( application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateInactive || application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateBackground  )
{
    UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard"
                                                bundle: nil];
    UIViewController *viewController= [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NotificationsViewController"];
    UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                            initWithRootViewController:viewController];
    [_window setRootViewController:nav];

     }
}
```

Comment: I also suggest including the `NotificationsViewController` class file and then using that instead of `UIViewController` as the data type.

Comment: Thank you, the navigation bar is appearing and I've included the class file in the .m file. However, one of my label has magically disappeared. Do you know why that is?

Comment: Nope, if your having more issues feel free to post another question.